# Ruby variable hashes {} for all

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables

I am trying here for detect which part of arrays have "a value"

The select method is looking like:

```
  a = content.select { |n| n == "a value" }
```

I tried to make it count positions:

```
  a = content.select { |n| n == "a value" }
      b = n + 1
```

and when i tried use that n variables for out of select. i had :

```
undefined local variable or method `n'
```

Comment: What's the whole error you're getting?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `n'

Comment: just look last code. is it have any problem ?

Comment: `b = n + 1` is outside the scope of your select, so it's correctly telling you that `n` doesn't exist there.  `n` only exists between the curly braces `{}`.

Comment: okkkay. how to use that n outside of select ? probably that is my right questino

Comment: Having done the select, apply a `.each` to the results to iterate through the set of selected objects and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: Do you want to find the first `n` and return the incremented value? Or do you want to select all values, and then increment all of them?

Comment: @nathanvda If the goal is to get the first one, then `find` would be far better than `select`...

Comment: look i have a array. and i select a array value. and tried that value is  which value of array. like array[5] after +1 and make it array[6] thats mean i found a value on my array. and i want to that value +1

Comment: You seem to be confusing values with indices.  They're two different things.  `select` yields a set of values, not their indices.

Comment: What does this have to do with hash functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [`Array#index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.0.preview2/Array.html#method-i-index):

```
content = [ "b value", "a value", "x value", "z value", "a value" ]

content.index("a value")
# => 1
```

If you want to know *all* positions that contain this value

```
content = [ "b value", "a value", "x value", "z value", "a value" ]
content.each_with_index.select { |v, _i| v == 'a value' }.map { |_v, i| i }
# => [1,4]
```

Comment: ...or `content.each_index.select { |i| content[i] == 'a value' }`, which, arguably, reads better, and also avoids the need for `.map { |_v, i| i }` (which could instead be written, `.map(&:last)`).